# Verifiyng behavior of mock type without instance controlling

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I'm developing custom runner of JUnit for internal purposes and, for instance, I've introduced custom annotation for test methods which on applying should make my runner to run method with this annotation after all other test methods without this annotation.

I want to write junit test to verify behavior of my custom runner.

Test class:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    @CustomAnnotation
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
       System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

An abstract code that will test my runner:

```
public class MyCustomRunnerTest {
    @Test
    public void order() throws InitializationError {
        // Arrange
        // Some code of mocking library might be placed here

        // Act
        MyCustomRunner runner = new MyCustomRunner(TestClass.class);
        runner.run(new RunNotifier());

        // Assert
        // Here I want to verify that method test1() has been called
        // after method test2()
    }
}
```

Is there any mocking libraries that will allow me to perform such verification? Or may be is there any other way to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not extract the logic that determines the run order of test methods into a separate class or method? This method should return a list of test method names (or other descriptors) in order in which they will run. Then your testing will come down to passing it the test class and asserting that the output is { "test2", "test1" }. No mocking required.

**A Better Solution**

Use RunListener to log test methods as they are being run by your runner. You of course will have your own MyCustomRunner class, but the rest of the code can stay as in the example below:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RunnerTest {
  // dummy "custom" test runner
  public static class MyCustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public MyCustomRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
      super(klass);
    }
  }

  public static class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test1() {}

    @Test
    public void test2() {}
  }

  @Test
  public void myCustomRunnerExecutesTestsInOrder() throws InitializationError {
    RunNotifier notifier = new RunNotifier();
    Collection<String> runTestMethods = new ArrayList<>();
    notifier.addListener(new RunListener() {
      @Override
      public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        runTestMethods.add(description.getMethodName());
      }
    });

    new MyCustomRunner(TestClass.class).run(notifier);
    // assert that the collection contains methods names in the specified order
    assertThat(runTestMethods, contains("test1", "test2"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is my current solution. Just capture standard output of my test class and compare it with the expected string. But I wanted to avoid this and tried to perform this verification via some more correct way. So do you think it is acceptable solution for this task and no any mocking libraries are required?

Comment: No mocking is required. Capturing output is one way to do this, but JUnit actually provides nice facilities for inspecting test run progress. See my updated reply.

Comment: Nice, it's more clean and correct way than just capturing output from execution.